# Check process status in new logcat of Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Recently android studio has introduced a new Logcat. The previous one had a feature through which we could select a specific process according to its name. That also showed if the process was alive or dead.

[image]

Now in the new Logcat it only shows process-id in log messages but does not show which process of the app is running which is dead. Am I missing something? or does it actually lacks this feature?

Answer (score 0):

you're right.

**Even when I looked at it, the new logcat seems to have lost its comfortable UI for viewing process status.**

============================

**Instead, the new logcat outputs logs like the one below, so you can see the status only for the currently running process.**

---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (22737) for package com.google.samples.apps.sunflower ----------------------------

[image]

---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (22737) for package com.google.samples.apps.sunflower ----------------------------

[image]

============================

**but,
If this is inconvenient, you can use the old logcat.**

(Currently based on Android Studio's Flamingo Stable)
Settings - Experimental - Logcat (Uncheck Enable new Logcat tool window)

[image]

============================

Maybe it's better to get accustomed to the new logcat, but
**If anyone knows of another better way, please let me know.**